# Error upgrading Magento CE 1.6.2 to 1.9.1

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to upgrade Magento but I'm getting this error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:1275:"Error in file: "/backup/home2/devnoc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/data/sales_setup/data-upgrade-1.6.0.4-1.6.0.5.php" - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main.base_tax_refunded' in 'field list', query was: UPDATE `sales_flat_order_item` AS `main`
 INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(citem.row_total) AS `amount_refunded`, SUM(citem.base_row_total) AS `base_amount_refunded`, SUM(citem.base_tax_amount) AS `base_tax_refunded`, SUM(citem.discount_amount) AS `discount_refunded`, SUM(citem.base_discount_amount) AS `base_discount_refunded`, `oitem`.`item_id` FROM `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AS `citem`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_creditmemo` AS `c` ON c.entity_id = citem.parent_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `o` ON o.entity_id = c.order_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS `oitem` ON oitem.order_id = o.entity_id AND oitem.product_id=citem.product_id GROUP BY `oitem`.`item_id`) AS `selected`
SET `main`.`amount_refunded` = `selected`.`amount_refunded`, `main`.`base_amount_refunded` = `selected`.`base_amount_refunded`, `main`.`base_tax_refunded` = `selected`.`base_tax_refunded`, `main`.`discount_refunded` = `selected`.`discount_refunded`, `main`.`base_discount_refunded` = `selected`.`base_discount_refunded`
WHERE (main.item_id = selected.item_id)";i:1;s:925:"#0 /backup/home2/devnoc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /backup/home2/devnoc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(407): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('data-upgrade', '1.6.0.4', '1.6.0.8')
#2 /backup/home2/devnoc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(286): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeData('1.6.0.4', '1.6.0.8')
#3 /backup/home2/devnoc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(269): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyDataUpdates()
#4 /backup/home2/devnoc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(351): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()
#5 /backup/home2/devnoc/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /backup/home2/devnoc/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:3:"bsk";}
```

I started with a fresh copy `of Magento 1.9.1 and imported my 1.6.2` database to run the update.

Any help on exactly what steps I need to take would be much appreciated.

Comment: does table citem have a column named base_row_total?

Comment: I do not see any table called citem in the database

Comment: Wait... when you say you imported your 1.6.2 database, do you mean you overwrote the 1.9.1 database?  I'm not familiar with magento, but I have done manual upgrades in the past...

Comment: I didn't overwrite anything. I am essentially following this guide and am on the database upgrade step 3. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database
There seems to be an issue on this step when Magento is trying to update my database to the newer version.

Comment: looking over the update query in more detail, it's table sales_flat_creditmemo_item that's aliased as citem , how about that table?

Comment: Yes, the column base_row_total is in the sales_flat_creditmemo_item table.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use ssh. Using the ssh you can easily update magento. Before start updating make sure you have backup of files and database. Once you have the backup go to folder where you have installed magento. Suppose document path is /var/www/html then go to html folder using this command.

```
cd /var/www/html
```

then use this command

```
./mage list-upgrades
```

you will see result something like this
Updates for community:

```
Mage_All_Latest: 1.6.2 => 1.9.1.0
Lib_Js_Mage: 1.6.2 => 1.9.1.0
Lib_Varien: 1.6.2 => 1.9.1.0
```

It means that your Magento will be upgraded to version 1.9.1.0

Enter this command to change the upgrade channel to stable
./mage config-set preferred_state stable

After channel selection you can upgrade your Magento to Magento 1.9.x.x using this command:

```
./mage upgrade-all --force
```

If "./mage upgrade-all --force" will not work, you can try to execute this command:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

You will see upgraded packages on your screen:

```
Package upgraded: community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.1.0
Package upgraded: community/Lib_Mage 1.9.1.0
Package upgraded: community/Lib_ZF 1.11.1.0
```

Now your files are updated but now it's time to update database. but first delete cache and session using this command.

```
rm -rf var/cache var/session
```

Now run this command.

```
php -f ./index.php
```

You may need to run this command 2-3 times but if it shows instantly result then run the admin url on browser. After login you can see upgraded version in footer.

Comment: When I run command php -f ./index.php I get the same error that I posted in my original post. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: May be your old modules are conflicting. Try to disable third party modules and then try.

Answer (score 0):

use a simple approach to update magento.

```
 1. Take Backup of your magento files and DB.
 2. login to magento connect.
 3. click on "check for update" button
 4. you will see there is update for "Mage_All_Latest". Update Mage_All_Latest only.
```

And your magneto is update without any issue.